# Blender 2.76b crashes windows xp on startup

Tags: error, windows, installation

I appreciate all your helps.  I find this software incompatibility very frustrating.  I think I remember Blender v2.76b running successfully on my laptop machine in the past.  There have been many application updates on my machine since then and today Blender no longer runs for me.  Tried some other Blender versions (v2.76a, v2.70a) but they do not run either.  The runtime result (hung program then blue screen) is the same whether Blender is started from the cmd line or from a windows shortcut.  Yes, I updated all the vcredist_x86_year files.

Then I tried the following from the cmd line:

```
C:\Program Files\Blender276a\blender.exe --debug-memory --debug-gpumem --debug-all > C:\Temp\results.txt
```

And here is the contents of the file results.txt:

```
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
read file 
  Version 272 sub 2 date unknown hash unknown

ordered
 OBCube
 OBLamp
 OBCamera
ED_screen_refresh: set screen
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender276b\2.76\python
FRS_set_context: context 0x0027A4C8 scene 0x0DACD558
```

The windows system event manager reports two log errors:

```
(#1) Event Type:    Error
Event Source:   System Error
Event Category: (102)
Event ID:   1003

Event ID - 1003
This error may caused by corrupted or improper driver, or may be due to a bug in device driver program that you installed for any of the hardware. Check the memory dump file that may usually generated by this event (Windows XP), which will help you to troubleshoot which is the driver causing this error.


(#2) Event Type:    Error
Event Source:   DCOM
Event Category: None
Event ID:   10010

Description:
The server {7F6316B4-4D69-4765-B0A3-B2598F2FA80A} 
did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
```

I think this #2 error predates the Blender issue.

Comment: Event ID - 1003 in combination with bluescreen suggests that your graphics driver crashes. BTW Windows XP is *very* out dated, doesn't receive security updates anymore and therefore shouldn't be connected to the internet.

Comment: I appreciate all comments.  Even ones I may not fully agree with.  For example my XP system is full of still valuable legacy software and custom software compiled just for it.  These older softwares cannot migrate successfully to any current Windows OS (although a subset of them could).  It would cost considerable money.  Security is handled with two commercial scanner products.  Complete system backups handle any other compromise.  Importantly Event ID 1003 says check memory dump file to determine which driver is responsible.  Yes, but where is it located.  Thank you whoever edited my post.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/171372/where-can-i-find-blue-screen-of-death-crash-dump Using a legacy system is entirely valid. You should be aware of the security implications when connecting it to the internet though.

Comment: Well said.  It appears my graphics driver for the Intel 945GM chipset
got into difficulty and needed to be updated and/or refreshed.

The driver download webpage is at:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81509
/Graphics-Drivers-for-Mobile-Intel-945GM-Express-Chipset-Family .  A clean reinstall of that driver fixed all my problems.  I no longer have anything to complain about now.  Interesting that the Intel webpage said those driver downloads available only through 11-Oct-2019 because EOL.